# How do I copy an instance of an object and if that object changes, the instance doesn't?

Tags: c#

I have a very simple question that is taking me a long time to figure out... How do I copy an object of an item and if that object changes, the instance doesn't?

For example, in my code I have this:

```
nextMove[i] = nextCell;
listOfNextMoves.Add(new State(nextMove));
nextMove[i] = Cell.Empty;
```

the nextMove that I have added to my listOfNextMoves changes to what the third line did.... How do I make it so if nextMove[i] changes, the nextMove inside of the list does not change?

In python, if I wanted to do

`tempBoard = genBoard`

I would have to do this

```
tempBoard = list(genBoard)
```

I am sorry if I am not clear, I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: You need to use deep cloning, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: Doesn't need deep cloning since he is replacing nextMove[i].

Comment: It would help to know what the classes of `nextMove`, nextMove[i]` and `listOfNextMoves` are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ToList() function creates a copy of a list:

```
nextMoveCopy = nextMove.ToList();
```

You can also use the constructor for most collection classes:

```
nextMoveCopy = new ArrayList(nextMove); 
nextMoveCopy = new List< GameBoard >(nextMove); 
nextMoveCopy = new ObservableCollection< GameBoard >(nextMove);
```

Do NOT use ReadOnlyCollection for this. Instead of making a copy, it creates a read-only wrapper around the original list.

Comment: Yes, but the instances in the list will be the same.

Comment: Look at the sample. This will work as long as he is replacing nextMove[i].

Comment: Actually working the sample out made me realize you are right, he doesn't need a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

In general, objects in C# cannot be copied.

However, many specific objects provide ways to duplicate themselves. Usually this is indicated by implementing the `ICloneable` interface. For example, `string` implements `ICloneable` so you can create a new string with the same value as an existing string by calling `String.Clone` and casting the result from an `object` to a `string`. Since strings are immutable, this isn't very useful. You never need to clone a string to protect it's value from changing, because it can't be changed. For other objects, though, it's more useful.

Arrays can also be cloned. For example:

```
var myArray = new MyType[3];
myArray[1] = new MyType("some parameter");
myArray[2] = new MyType("some other parameter");
var myOtherArray = (myArray[]) myArray.Clone();
myOtherArray[2].Parameter // value is "some other parameter"
myOtherArray[2] = new MyType("a whole other parameter");
myOtherArray[2].Parameter // value is "a whole other parameter"
myArray[2].Parameter // value is still "some other parameter"
```

Because arrays contain references to objects, cloning the array won't clone all the objects *in* the array.

```
myArray[1].Parameter = "changed parameter";
myOtherArray[1].Parameter // value is now "changed parameter"
```

Here there are two different arrays, with two different objects in the third spot, but *the same* object in the second spot.

Generally, `Clone` is "messy". Many complicated objects are not cloneable, and just because an type implements `ICloneable` doesn't mean it works as expected. `Clone` usually creates what's called a shallow copy, which means that the object itself is cloned, but other objects it references are not cloned. Sometimes `Clone` will create a deep copy, where all references the object has are cloned too. Sometimes it will mix them. Sometimes developers inherit from types which implement `ICloneable` but don't provide a new implementation for their subtype. Sometimes they forget to make their implementations virtual. All the problems with `ICloneable` are outside the scope of this answer but, as a rule, avoid `Clone` if at all possible.

Instead, use copy constructors if available. Many objects can be created using a reference to other objects of the same type as a template. For example

```
var myList = new List<string>(){"a","b"};
var myOtherList = new List<string>(myList); // a copy of myList!
```

You can also use the linq extensions to turn arrays and lists into copied arrays and lists.

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
var myArray = new[]{"a","b"};
var myOtherArray = myArray.ToArray(); // creates a new array
var myList = myArray.ToList(); // creates a new list
```

In your example, try

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
nextMove[i] = nextCell;
listOfNextMoves.Add(new State(nextMove.ToArray()));
nextMove[i] = Cell.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out!

I just had to do

```
nextMove[i] = nextCell;
listOfNextMoves.Add(new State((Cells[])nextMove.Clone()));
nextMove[i] = Cell.Empty;
```

and it created a deep copy of the instance for me!

Comment: Actually depending on how the `Clone()` method was implemented it could be either a shallow copy or a deep copy (most likely a shallow copy though). Your code works because it doesn't matter if the copy is shallow or deep. I would go with Jonathan Allen's solution though since the intent is more obvious.